# Рекурсивный вызов в libev (EVBREAK_RECURSE) при организации многопоточного сервера

Tags: c, многопоточность, libev

Суть алгоритма (c libevent все работало):

1. Используется один  луп на прослушивание сокета.
2. Запускается несколько тредов, они ложатся в спячку. Каждый тред присоединяет событие на Read
3. По ассепту они все пробуждаются, и кто успел... пробудился первый, тот и захватил мютекс, взял соединение...
4. Блокировку снимаем, треды засыпаю., а наш тред отрабатывает...
5. Берется пул и кладется в него файловый дескриптор и необходимые
       буфера (в/в) и структуры  . id
       блокируем мьютексом.
6. Далее мы
       организуем самопально noblocked
       чтение, код типа `buffer_event`
7. После того как данные будут отданы,
   освобождаем пул и тред засыпает.
   далее п 3.

Имею ошибку:

```
Assertion failed: (("libev: ev_loop recursion during release detected", loop_done != EVBREAK_RECURSE)), function ev_run, file ev.c, line 2392.
```

код [github](https://github.com/akalend/mtserver) 
Читаем файл `INSTALL` - для большитнства unix систем должно скомпилироваться без проблем, 
должна быть установлена libev, если не компилится, то правим пути в Makefile.am и потом все с первого шага ./autogen.sh

Comment: Странный алгоритм.

Почему бы accept() не делать только в одном thread, а из остальных организовать пул. Они висят на семафоре очереди, в которую accept-thread кладет новый сокет и делает post.

Далее thread, взявший сокет из очереди работает с ним. И nonblock в такой схеме вообще не нужен. 

Пул thread-ов обработчиков при желании можно сделать динамическим с high-low watermarks.

Comment: Есть пример кода?

Алгоритм взят из Стивенсона "Разработка сетевых приложений", он же используется с libevent в memcached, и в моем клоне все работало.  Все сделано по образу и подобию....

но с libev упорно не хочет, или что-то я не учел.

Comment: Есть программа на C в Linux (довольно большая). Если время будет, вытащу оттуда куски в один файл, как пример.

С libevent я не сталкивался, прочитал сейчас в Вики и вот эта фраза:

    Using callbacks on signals, libevent makes it easy to write secure signal handlers as none of the user supplied signal handling code runs in the signal's context.

вызывает некоторые сомнения в ее отлаженности во всех ОС.

Я вообще настороженно отношусь к алгоритмам, завязанным на обработку сигналов.

--

У Вас какая ОС?

Comment: @akalend, извините за задержку. 

[Положил](http://zalil.ru/34093161) программу с примером обработки в пуле потоков.

Извините, быстро выдрать относящийся к делу (и остающимся работоспособным) код ни из этой тестовой 

    Тесты измерения времени обработки сетевых соединений различными  способами (клиенты и сервер на одной машине)

 программы, ни из разрабатываемого сервера (о котором я упоминал) времени не хватает.

Посмотрите, часть относящаяся к Вашему вопросу это в основном стороки 1164-1173 и 1212-1224 (ну и вызываемые оттуда функции).

Успехов.

Comment: спасибо, обязательно посмотрю
Ось продакшен Linux & разработка OsX 
позможна разработка полностью на Linux (epoll)

Answer (score 1):

Я делал классическую схему "кто успел, тот и съел": как и вы заводил пул потоков (далее воркеров), в каждом воркере запускал ev_loop, для accept создавал столько же ev_io вотчеров, колбек делал им один. Блокировку осуществлял при помощи механизма `ev_set_loop_release_cb (loop, void (*release)(EV_P) throw (), void (*acquire)(EV_P) throw ())`

Мутекс, который лочится в `acquire()` и отпускается в `release()` для каждого цикла свой. Лочится он перед запуском цикла, а внутри цикла, когда нужно, отпускается и обратно забирается когда нужно, при помощи ваших колбеков.

В общем картина такая: для асинхронного accept прилетает эвент всем воркерам, для кого первым отработал `accept`, тому и возвратился дескриптор клиентского сокета, остальным вернулось `-1/EAGAIN`. Далее уже дескриптор полностью обслуживается циклом, на котором он сработал. Распределение нагрузки получается достаточно равномерной.

Если что-то непонятно - дополню.

Пример на C++11: https://gitlab.com/snippets/8201

Comment: Есть _небольшая_ вероятность, что автор вопроса, заданного в 2012 году, не увидит ваш ответ. Тем не менее, ответ наверняка будет полезен будущим читателям.

Comment: Да, я обратил внимание на дату, но по тегу libev только один вопрос, причём без конечного ответа. Так что цель "для будущих поколений" и ставилась. Ещё малость кода добавлю.

Comment: Автор увидел, спасибо. Тут меня как раз недавно спрашивали как сделать многотредовую обработку для libev, обещал сделать пример кода.